# (librosa)valueError:Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition, training-data

here is my training data

```
train_audio_path = 'C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Bureau/input1/train/audio1/'

all_wave = []
all_label = []
for label in labels:
    print(label)
    waves = [f for f in os.listdir(train_audio_path + '/'+ label) if f.endswith('.wav')]
    for wav in waves:
        samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(train_audio_path + '/' + label + '/' + wav, sr = 16000)
        if(len(samples)>=16000 or len(samples)<=16000) : 
            all_wave.append(samples)
            all_label.append(label)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDc53.png)

Here is my model:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
metric = 'val_accuracy'
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10, min_delta=0.0001) 
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.hdf5', monitor=metric, verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
# Display model architecture summary 
history=model.fit(x_tr, y_tr ,epochs=100, callbacks=[es,mc], batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8428/2388281761.py in <module>
      1 # Display model architecture summary
----> 2 history=model.fit(x_tr, y_tr ,epochs=100, callbacks=[es,mc], batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    104       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    105   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 106   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    107 
    108 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I've tried googling the error but i didn't find a suitable solution to the problem
++++ Any help would be greatly appreciated ++++

Comment: try this : `history=model.fit(np.asarray(x_tr), np.asarray(y_tr) ,epochs=100, callbacks=[es,mc], batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))`

Comment: Please [edit] your post so that it doesn't contain [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @I'mahdi I tried it but still the same error . I have no idea why I'm getting this error again  Thanks for your help.